# Imprimir apenas os dois últimos dígitos de um ano

Tags: javascript, data

Como fazer para que o ano tenha apenas dois dígitos?

```js
data = new Date().getFullYear();

console.log(data);

console.log(data.substr(2,4));
```

Answer (score 8):

Como [o retorno de `getFullYear()` é um número](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear#Return_value), não dá para usar `substr` (pois este método só existe [para strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)).

Neste caso, você pode pegar o resto da divisão por 100:

```js
let ano = new Date().getFullYear();

console.log(ano % 100); // 19
```

---

Para o caso do ano ser 2003, por exemplo, aí é necessário um pouco mais de trabalho, já que o resultado será `3` e não será impresso com o zero à esquerda.

Você pode usar [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para colocar o zero à frente (e nesse caso será necessário converter para string antes, usando [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)), ou fazer um processo mais "manual" para adicionar o zero:

```js
// alternativa 1: usar padStart
let ano = 2003;
console.log((ano % 100).toString().padStart(2, 0)); // 03

// alternativa 2: calcular o resto da divisão e adicionar o zero manualmente
ano = ano % 100;
console.log(`${ano < 10 ? '0' : ''}${ano}`); // 03
```

---

Existe ainda uma outra alternativa, usando o método [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). Neste caso, basta especificar a quantidade mínima de dígitos que você quer exibir, que o restante é preenchido com zeros à esquerda:

```js
let ano = 2003;
console.log((ano % 100).toLocaleString('pt', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 })); // 03

ano = 2019;
console.log((ano % 100).toLocaleString('pt', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 })); // 19
```

O parâmetro `'pt'` refere-se ao locale (no caso, "pt" é o código para "português"), e influencia em alguns detalhes no formato de saída (como usar o ponto ou a vírgula para separar os milhares ou as casas decimais, caso use o locale em português ou inglês, por exemplo). Mas neste caso específico, como os valores são menores que 1000 e não há casas decimais, não faz tanta diferença assim. O que é importante neste caso é o valor de `minimumIntegerDigits`.

Comment: Agora só no caso do ano ser 2103... rs Até lá nóis já taremos 

Comment: @Sam Código *future proof*, é melhor prevenir que remediar :-)

Answer (score 8):

Convertemos para string, depois pegamos somente os dois últimos caracteres:

```js
data = new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
console.log(data);
```